# Controlling processes from Python

Tags: python, process, pid

I want to control several subprocesses of the same type from python (I am under linux).
I want to:

- Start them.
- Stop them.
- Ask if they are still running.

I can start a processes with with spawnl, and get the pid. Using this pid I can stop it with kill. And I am sure there is also a way to ask if it is running with the pid.

The problem is, what if the following happens:
I start a process, remember the pid. The process ends without me noticing and another completely different process starts getting assigned the same pid. I attempt to kill my process, I kill a completely different one.

What is the better way to start and control processes in python?
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [subprocess.Popen](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess.popen#subprocess.Popen) to start the other process, and save the resulting [Popen object](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess.popen#popen-objects).  With methods on that object, you can check if the process still alive, wait for it to finish, terminate it, kill it -- all without any risk of pid-based confusion!  As a plus, this is also a more cross-platform approach, though you may not care specifically in this case.